# Binding Label content to Self string field but no result

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, label

I'm trying what should be an easy bind in my user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.FlowNode" ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

With the underlying code being:

```
public partial class FlowNode : UserControl
{
    public FlowNode()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Header { get { return "Testing"; } };
}
```

However, the label stays blank. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type FlowNode}}}.
```

Comment: You also need to add an `xmlns` for the namespace that `FlowNode` is defined in.

Answer (score 2):

`{RelativeSource Self}` refers to the `Label` instance, not your user control.

Instead of using a `RelativeSource`, you should set the UserControl's `DataContext` to itself, as karmicpuppet suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, set the DataContext of the UserControl to itself.  "this.DataContext = this".  And remove the RelativeSource in your binding.

Comment: You should never do this in a UserControl - it's a recipe for bugs. When you set the DataContext to itself you break any Bindings set on an instance of the control that use the inherited DataContext by overridding the inherited value. Since you're doing it from inside it's impossible to see from the XAML that's using the control. Instead set the DataContext of a named element in the UserControl's XAML, like a root Grid.

Comment: I definitely agree in your comment about "this.DataContext = this" is generally not a good design practice, I guess I'm just suggesting to the OP that this is the most direct way to fix his problem based on the facts he gave above.  =)

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way to get access to 'Me'/'this' in xaml in my opinion is to put a Name on your control :
    <   UserControl 
             x:Class="MyApp.FlowNode"
             ...
             Name="MyFlowNode" >
And then, if you bind to your control's property or dp, you use ElementName syntax.

So you don't break the DataContext of your control.

There might be a way with RelativeSource FindAncestor binding, but i don't see advantages over that one.

But *do not* set DataContext of your Control to itself, otherwise it will loose awareness of its DataContext.